# Hyphenation with colon as special character

Tags: symbols, hyphenation, hyphenat

I need to define hyphenation for words that contain colons. Using `hyphanat` package returns error `Not a letter. \hyphenation{Konsument:`. Any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\hyphenation{Konsument:innen-zusammen-schlüsse}

\setlength\textwidth{1mm} % just for this example
\begin{document}
    Konsument:innenzusammenschlüsse
\end{document}
```

Comment: I assume you want to allow a line break after the `:` character as well as hyphenation within the "Konsument" substring. Is this correct? Please advise.

Comment: Honestly, I don't think so (but OP would have to answer that). "Konsument:innen" is an "inclusive" (aka politically correct) shorthand to use instead of "Konsumenten und Konsumentinnen", i.e. both male and female forms in German. It doesn't lend itself to a line break easily, I think.

Comment: @Ingmar your answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"letter" here means has a lower-case code. Also, tex will not hyphenate the first word (unless using luatex) so I added `x`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\lccode`\:=`\:
\hyphenation{Konsument:innen-zusammen-schlüsse}

\setlength\textwidth{1mm} % just for this example
\begin{document}
x    Konsument:innenzusammenschlüsse
\end{document}
```